# deselecting or disabling grabbing of images and links

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I built an application from HTML5, CSS, and Javascript. The issue is I want to stop the mouse from grabbing images and links on the page.

For example, if I hover the mouse over an image in my application and hold down the mouse, then move the mouse while holding down, a copy or translucent view of the image comes with the pointer. Until I let go of the mousedown. I would like to disable this if I can. The same goes for any anchor tags on my page (links).

Hope that makes somewhat sense. I have been searching and tried multiple solutions like:

1. Making the element: `draggable=false`
2. Using:

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
       document.onmousemove = function() {
           return false;
       };
   };
   ```

   not sure if this is written correctly...
3. Body:  `oncontextmenu="return false;">`

Sorry, cannot seem to get code block to function correctly for the above???

Anyone know if this can be done?

Comment: If you're trying to keep users from copying your images, forget it. There are too many ways that cannot be stopped.

Comment: Any reason why? Sometimes this is an enormously useful feature: dragging links to the Home button, dragging links to the Bookmarks icon, dragging links to Desktop (creates shortcuts), copying images into e-mails, etc. etc. These features are browser based and may not be preventable.

Comment: It is a native browser behavior, you can't stop it.

Comment: but can be a basic copy protection. i am interested too, because i made a local info-scheme in html5+jQuery for lame users. in this case blocking dragging and copying it's enough

Comment: Thanks everyone for the responses, just want to give an update. I have not been able to get back to this project to resolve my issue. But I will be throughout the next week or so. So I will keep you posted. Thanks again! The suggestions have given me a few more approaches to attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution to

- prevent highlighting text ✓
- prevent copying text ✓
- prevent dragging objects like images ✓
- disable right click completely ✓

#### JavaScript with jQuery reference:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // disabling text highlight on all browser    
    $('body').each(function(){
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-touch-callout': 'none',
            '-webkit-user-select': 'none',
            '-khtml-user-select': 'none',
            '-moz-user-select': 'none',
            '-ms-user-select': 'none',
            'user-select': 'none'
        });
    });

    // disabling cut, copy, paste of DOM elements
    $(document).bind('cut copy paste', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

    // disabling image dragging
    $('img').bind('mousedown selectstart', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});

// disabling right click completelly
function mischandler(){
    return false;
}
function mousehandler(e){
    var myevent = (isNS) ? e : event;
    var eventbutton = (isNS) ? myevent.which : myevent.button;
    if((eventbutton==2)||(eventbutton==3)) return false;
}
var isNS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape") ? 1 : 0;
if(navigator.appName == "Netscape") {
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN||Event.MOUSEUP);
}
document.oncontextmenu = mischandler;
document.onmousedown = mousehandler;
document.onmouseup = mousehandler;
```

#### CSS code

```css
body * {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

[jsFiddle sandbox](http://jsfiddle.net/eapo/XcZFY/)

Comment: mousedown or selectstart never call on my image tags when it starts dragging them. I also have all of the same css properties and my links and images are still draggable.

Comment: for me still working after so many years in modern browser to. please prove your report.

Comment: iPads 3D touch feature will still drag elements with this styling. You have to add draggable=false inside the a or img tag element to prevent this drag feature on tablets.

Comment: Thank you for this @TheJeff, i hope there is a global solution for iPads. if someone find a way, please publish. thx.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery:

```
$(document).on('mouseover mousedown', 'a, img', function() {
    return false;
});
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/pXj7V/)

Please note that this will not stop people copying your images/links - they can still view the page source. It will only prevent the default browser behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try:

```
$("img").draggable("option", "draggable", false);
```

And it should keep your image tags from being draggable.

[New update]

It probably might not work for your 'a' anchors though, that might have something to do with the browser.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to newer iPads or iPhones with forcetouch or 3D touch:

All link and image tags are draggable within safari by default, none of the CSS tricks for user-select or touch-callout fix it. Neither do the event blockers for ("mousedown" or "selectstart") fix it.

Simply add draggable=false directly into the tags

```
<a href="https://www.w3schools.com" draggable="false">Visit W3Schools.com!</a>
<img src="smiley.gif" draggable="false" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
```